# Django models subtraction issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, web-deployment

```
class Finances(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default={Student.student_name})
    total_fees = models.IntegerField(default=3500)
    paid_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance = total_fees - paid_amount
    balance_fees = models.IntegerField({balance})
```

I need the balance_fees model to hold the value of a subtraction of total_fees - paid_amount which is held by the balance.
I get an error when making migrations 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'IntegerField' and 'IntegerField'

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have several options:

**Option 1**: A **python** property

```py
class Finances(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, ... )
    total_fees = models.IntegerField(default=3500)
    paid_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @property
    def balance_fees(self):
        return self.total_fees - self.paid_amount
```

- Pros: is always up-to-date.
- Cons: not index friendly (you can't index database by this field because is not on database)

**Option 2**: A **django model property** update overriding save:

```py
class Finances(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, ... )
    total_fees = models.IntegerField(default=3500)
    paid_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance_fees = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.balance_fees = self.total_fees - self.paid_amount
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

- Pros: index friendly, you can include this field on your queries.
- Cons: only up-to-date after save.

**Option 3**: A **django model property** updated via pre-save signal:

```py
class Finances(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, ... )
    total_fees = models.IntegerField(default=3500)
    paid_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance_fees = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# ---

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Finances


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Finances)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.balance_fees = sender.total_fees - sender.paid_amount
```

- Pros: index friendly, you can include this field on your queries.
- Cons: only up-to-date after save.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method onside your model:

```
    @property
    def  balance(self):
      val = self.total_fees - self.paid_amount
      return val
```

Remove these two lines on tour model:

```
 balance = total_fees - paid_amount
 balance_fees = models.IntegerField({balance})
```

And now you can use balance as a field of your model in your views and template